# using the map operator using Observables

Tags: angular, observable

Below I do a map after subscribe, but I would like to use the map operator instead. Can anyone point me in right direction?

```
  getChildren(node: any) {
    this.filter = {
      codedName: node.id
    };
    this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(this.filter)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data", data);
      data.map(child => {
        this.children.push({
          id: child.codedName,
          name: `${child.codedName} ${child.preferredName}`,
          hasChildren: true
        });
      });
    });
    // return this.asyncChildren.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c));
    return this.children.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c));
  }
```

Comment: When you say "I would like to use the map operator instead" do you mean the observable operator called `map`?"  which is different than the `.map` Array prototype method?  Just wanting to make sure I understand.

Comment: hi @TobiahRex yes, the map observable operator

Comment: Have you investigated the docs?  Here's a promising [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/16/exploring-rx-operators-map.html)

Comment: @TobiahRex yes, but it does not explain how I transform an array of objects to another array of objects. This is what I need to do. I only need part of the object, and assign three values to the new keys called id, name, hasChildren as in the example code.

Comment: @TobiahRex when I try to use the map operator instead and then push the result to the children array I get undefined. https://jsfiddle.net/qmzh3yes/#&togetherjs=IOhrx8MlOh

Comment: I believe you're missing the Observable source declaration | using `from`.  See my answer below for details.

Comment: You're going about this all wrong. Your values coming through are arrays. You need to treat it like a stream of arrays and not a stream of single objects.  the observable map operator is for STREAMS, the array map operator is for ARRAYS, so the array operator is appropriate for the items in a stream of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: your function should not modify this.children asynchronously and return it at the same time. Let's look at your code (Tobiah's answer has the same error).

1. You set `this.filter` value
2. You make async call
3. You immediately return mapped `this.children`

And this is wrong, because return will not wait for async call to finish.

By the way:

```
Rx.Observable.from(this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(this.filter))
```

It's redundant. It's like `Object.assign({})`, which you are using and is also redundant.

Moreover, your question is not enough explanatory. Do you need to keep data in `this.children` or you can get rid of it?

I would recommend making `getChildren` function async, like this:

```
interface Node {
  id: any;
  name: string;
  hasChildren: boolean;
}

getChildren(node: any): Observable<Node> {
  // is it necessary to bind this to state? it is suspicious side effect
  this.filter = {
    codedName: node.id
  };

  return this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(this.filter)
    .map((x: any[]) => 
      x.map(child => ({
        id: child.codedName,
        name: `${child.codedName} ${child.preferredName}`,
        hasChildren: true
      }))
    );
}
```

An idea you need to understand, is that **Observable.map will apply your function to every object, that appears on stream**. So if your stream provides arrays, **Observable.map will apply function on each array, not on their elements**. So you have something like this `(array) => doSmth(array)`. If you need to modify objects inside array, your function `doSmth` should do it.

Now you can subscribe to your function or use it in template with `async` pipe.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz I basically want to do this tree http://www.eclasscontent.com/index.php?language=en

Comment: and I use this tree component. The author is also telling the tree does not accept Observables and need to convert to a Promise using toPromise. This add one more layer of complexity.. Sorry.. https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/issues/514

Comment: An idea you need to understand, is that Observable.map will apply your function to every object, that appears on stream. So if your stream provides arrays, map will apply function on each array, not on their elements. So you have something like this `(array) => doSmth(array)`. If you need to modify objects inside array, your function doSmth should do it.

Comment: Converting Observable into Promise couldn't be easier. All you need to do is to call .toPromise() on stream. Like `this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(this.filter).map(doSmth).toPromise();` and later you will need to call `.then()` on your result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Lukasz help me a lot and I manage to solve it.

Here is the complete code I did taking into account the tips from Lukasz in his answer.

I hope this can help other so I attach the complete code for this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ITreeOptions } from "angular-tree-component";
import { EclassService } from "../../services/eclass.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component({
  selector: "app-async",
  template: `<tree-root #tree [options]="options" [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>`,
  styles: ["async-tree-example.component.css"]
})

export class AsyncTreeExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  options: ITreeOptions = {
    getChildren: this.getChildren.bind(this)
  };
  nodes = [];
  children = [];

  constructor(private eclassService: EclassService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const filter: any = { level: "1" };
    this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(filter).subscribe(data => {
      this.nodes = data.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.codedName,
          name: `${item.codedName} ${item.preferredName}`,
          hasChildren: true
        };
      });
    });
  }

  getChildren(node: any): Promise<object> {
    const filter = {
      codedName: node.id
    };

    return this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(filter)
      .map((x: any[]) => {
        return x.map(child => {
          if (child.level === "4") {
            return ({
              id: child.codedName,
              name: `${child.codedName} ${child.preferredName}`,
              hasChildren: false
            });
          } else {
            return ({
              id: child.codedName,
              name: `${child.codedName} ${child.preferredName}`,
              hasChildren: true
            });
          }
        });
      })
      .toPromise();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) this would seem to work.

---

1) Create a source from an Observable by using `from`

2) `map` to that source iterable, returning a mutation of whatever you want.

3) `subscribe` to that mapping.

```
getChildren(node: any) {
  this.filter = {
    codedName: node.id
  };

  const source = Rx.Observable.from(this.eclassService.getEclassNodes(this.filter));

  const children = source.map(child => ({
    id: child.codedName,
    name: `${child.codedName} ${child.preferredName}`,
    hasChildren: true
  });

  children.subscribe((child) => {
    this.children.push(child);
  });

  return this.children.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c));
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, still get the same error: if I console.log the child {id: undefined, name: "undefined undefined", hasChildren: true}. If i console log the this.children, I an array with the above object. Should be multple objects and not undefined data